# Weird textures on a sword i made for Minecraft 1.12.2

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have a problem with a sword i made for Minecraft 1.12.2, the sword appears in the tab and works well but the texture is not quite how i wanted (see the pic). I don't know what to do.

I am using the IDE IntelliJ IDEA and Java 1.8.0.

Here's the git repos : https://github.com/Akariiinnn/Mods-MC

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDsVV.png)

PS: i am new to modding

Comment: it just don't find the file, and it seems to don't be the good path. Are you sure you should use `sword:` and not `sword/` ? Also, are you sure you don't need to put the file extension ?

Comment: i replaced the line with : "sword/texture/items/epee_feu.png" but it did'nt seem to work, also, adding the assets folders in the resources directory brokes the mcmod.info and i don't know what to do about it

Comment: and what about `sword:texture/items/my_sword.png` ?

Comment: it's the same, i don't really know what to do from now...

Comment: Does my answer help you ?

Comment: not really, because i can't even create a package inside resources i can only create directories i think that's why it's broken.

Comment: No, such as It's not java code it's not package. Also, package is -for OS- folder. So just create/rename folder and it should be fine

Comment: do you have discord so we can talk easier ?

Comment: Sure: Elikill58#0743

Comment: Please include your code in the question, as text, as a [mcve]. Links can break, and content on github is almost sure to change. That makes the question useless for others with similar problems. Also describe your problem better. How did you expect your texture to turn out? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The issue come from names.

1. The model should be in `models/items`
2. You should use `textures/items` as package name
3. The `layer0` should be `sword:items/my_sword`

[Source](https://mcmodhelp.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials:_Items#Making_a_texture), you can check more [here](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Creating_Forge_mods#Setting_up_Item_Registration)